# Aligning a sprite image to center of a table cell

Tags: html, css

I made a sprite with all our icon images as the same image repeats a lot and I didn't want it loading over and over.

Below is an example of the CSS code

```
#visa{background: url('sprite.png') -69px 0; left: 0; width: 87px; height: 36px;}
```

The Visa icon is visible in the table, but it's aligned to the left, I need it alighted center

```
<tr>
<td><p id="visa"></p></td>
<td><p>Visa</p></td>
<td><img src="ok.png"></td>
<td><img src="ok.png"></td>
 </tr>
```

I've tried to align center the P tag and the td tag using 
aligh:center and text-align:center; neither are working for me.

I tried some position classes but couldn't get it working, but i may not have been using it correctly.

there is other styling I'd like to do to the cell as well like padding top/bottom but I need to get this sorted first.

What can I try ?

here is JS fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/dave5000/v4cgeo9z/

Comment: Have you tried to add `background-position: center;` to your css?

Comment: what tag would you add this to ?

Comment: Like so: `#visa{background: url('sprite.png') -69px 0; left: 0; width: 87px; height: 36px; background-position: center;}´. May be I missunderstood your question though, but worth a try, it is not a lot of code ;P

Comment: yes i tried this. Sadly it didn't work. - Thanks.

Comment: i've added a demo to show where i am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#visa{
  background: url('sprite.png'); 
  background-size: 36px;
  background-position: center;
  left: 0; 
  width: 87px; 
  height: 36px;
}
```

Don't really know the sizes of your image, but I guess this will do the trick.

EDIT:

Sorry for the wrong info, I messed up with copying from my example..

How about this?

```
 #visa{
   background: url('sprite.png'); 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   display: block;
   left: 0; 
   width: 87px; 
   height: 36px;
 }
```

EDIT 2:

After you added the demo, I was able to generate this solution:
[Fiddler Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v4cgeo9z/1/)

I removed the

```
left: 0;
```

and added the next css line:

```
display: inline-block;
```

My fiddler demo works for me, so let me know if it works for you as well

Comment: this didn't work the background-size: 36px; made my whole sprite 36px in width and repeated nearly 3 times ( really small image ) and wasn't aligned center.

Comment: doesn't work the  background-position: center; makes it dissapear every time. I've added a demo

Comment: I updated my answer. It is not needed to remove the 'left: 0;', but it is not making any difference if it's not there, since it's aligned left by default, which makes that line redundant in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

How open are you to using jQuery and plugins? Backstretch is a plugin that lets you set background images nicely, and works well with responsive design also. Here is a link, take a look it might be helpful!

http://www.jquery-backstretch.com/

If you can't use jQuery, what about the following:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <p id="visa">
            <img src="sprite.png" />
        </p>
    </td>
    <td><p>Visa</p></td>
    <td><img src="ok.png"></td>
    <td><img src="ok.png"></td>
</tr>

#visa{
    width: 87px;
    height: 36px;
}
#visa img {
    width: 87px;
    height: 36px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I can't use it.. I'd rather use css / html if possible. Thanks though.

Comment: I don't want to add the image to the P tag.. if that was the case i'd just add a small visa image to each cell i needed one. This is was I wanted to use CSS to pull the image in once.

Comment: Ok - can you give any more examples of what you've tried already?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `margin-left: 30%;` to your `#visa {` css. You can play around with the % to get the correct position, or even use px if you like.

```css
th {
  text-align: center!important;
}

thead > tr > th {
  padding:20px!important;
  background-color: #9fc5d0;
}

td {
  text-align: center!important;
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
}

#visa {
  background: url('http://www.davidstokes.com/1/payments/gg-sprite.png') -69px 0;
  margin-left: 30%;
  width: 87px;
  height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" width="40%">Method</th>
      <th width="20%">Deposit</th>
      <th width="20%">Withdrawal</th>
     
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><p id="visa"></p></td>
  <td>Visa</td>
  <td><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Free-PSD-blogging-icons-Bimbilini/32/ok.png"></td>
  <td><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Free-PSD-blogging-icons-Bimbilini/32/ok.png"></td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p id="visa"></p></td>
  <td>Visa</td>
  <td><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Free-PSD-blogging-icons-Bimbilini/32/ok.png"></td>
  <td><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Free-PSD-blogging-icons-Bimbilini/32/ok.png"></td>
 
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it helped